# Having issues with creating a age tool where you can change the value with a up and arrow tool

Tags: html, css

[image: image showing the code that should have been copied, as text, in the answer]

I'm trying to create a tool where it displays a label and gives you a up and down arrow where you can change the "Age" but when I refresh my page nothing happens?

Comment: Please include your code *as* code (written, in text) so that it can be copied to simplify reproduction of your problem. Further, what do you mean when you say: "*when [you] refresh [your] page nothing happens?*"

Comment: Check your spellings for `input` element. You have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I seems like you wrote **imput** instead of **input**.

Try this:

```
<div>
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input type="number" name="age" value="30" />
</div>
```